# A container for items for each taxonomy

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, blocks

I have a content-type called "Member", which has four taxonomy terms.

Now in my block, i want to display entries in a different DIV for each taxonomy.

For example all items with the taxonomy "Boss" should be placed inside the first DIV, items with the taxonomy "Manager" should be placed in the second DIV, and so on..

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

Create a new view content type

**add field Content: All taxonomy terms (checked Exclude from display )
add field Content: Title**

**add filter Content: Type (= Member)**

go to format select HTML list on settings **Grouping field Nr.1  select Content: All taxonomy terms** unchecked "**Use rendered output to group rows**"

from add create a block you will get a new block in your block page. 
[image]